# Inserting ArrayList<Integer> into List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to solve a leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/
I have to find out all the combinations (A combination is stored in an ArrayList) that add to a specified number. I have to store all the Combinations (ArrayLists) in an ArrayList. So I will have ArrayList of ArrayList (call it "ans").
But I am not able to add any combinations to this ans ArrayList. I am able to print out all the combinations but I have to return it in a 2d ArrayList only. The ans list is returning only empty lists at the end of the code flow.
I am attaching my code below

```
class Solution {
int[] candidates;
ArrayList<List<Integer>> ans;
void f(int index, int target, ArrayList<Integer> current){
    if (target == 0){
        System.out.println(current);
        this.ans.add(current);
        return;
    }
    if (target < 0) return;
    
    for(int i = index; i < candidates.length; i++){
        current.add(candidates[i]);
        target -= candidates[i];
        f(i, target, current);
        target += candidates[i];
        current.remove(current.size()-1);
    }
}
public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {
    this.ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    this.candidates = candidates;
    f(0, target, new ArrayList<>());
    return this.ans;
}
```

}

Input:  `[2,3,6,7] 7`

Output (contents of ans): `[[],[]]`

StdOut: `[2, 2, 3] [7]`

Comment: Every time you add `current.add(candidates[i]);` a short time later to remove the last element from that list again `current.remove(current.size()-1);` - So it should be no surprise that in the end your list ends up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OH GOD SPIDERS, Thanks!;
This is happening because I am not passing a copy of the current combination to the ans List.
I had to alter the basecase to

```
if (target == 0){
        this.ans.add(new ArrayList(current));
        return;
}
```

Comment: It would be much better to move your answer to a comment on the question (as it is a direct reply to another comment). If you really want to submit an answer then create a full post including the whole correct code.